# Custom css per category and per single post belong in each category

Tags: categories, customization, css

the condition is:

there's a wordpress site
that has 8 categories, and each category has sub-category, and each subcategory has several posts (and still will be updating/counting)  :

- Category A - 8 subcat
- Category B - 5 subcat
- Category C - 4 subcat
- Category D - 3 subcat
- Category E - 2 subcat
- Category F - 1 subcat
- Category G - 5 subcat
- Category H - 4 subcat

---

The body_class() function is already exist in header,
and I want to make

- Each category has different background image and custom header (ex: instead of Browsing the   "xx"    Category text- i'll be using custom words/image)
- For each single post page belong to certain category, the style is inherit. (i dont know how to explain that on english - but what I want to achieve is: A single post that belong to **category A** have the same style with **Category A** archive pages.

I did add:

```
    .category-A 
    { /* css here */ }

    .category-B
    { /* css here */ }

    etc
```

but for each single page, the styling did not work..

and to tweak single page that belong to category who-
I don't know the code.

So...
there's pretty much the rough description of my problem, though.
Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category archive pages can be styled using the body class as per your example - WordPress does this out of the box. But for single pages, you need to add this to `functions.php`:

```
function add_category_name($classes = '') {
   if(is_single()) {
      $category = get_the_category();
      $classes[] = 'category-'.$category[0]->slug; 
   }
   return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class','add_category_name');
```

This will add the body class to the single post, and you can style it with CSS.
In order to change the header text, you'll need to use a conditional statement in your archive page template.

```
if (in_category('this')) { 
    echo 'this';
} elseif (in_category('that')) { 
    echo 'that';
} else { }
```

Comment: Yes but doesn't work on the home page archive.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you would like to add a class based on the current category to the `<body>` of posts and category archives.

There is example code on the [`body_class` codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) which achieve this:

> To add a category class to single post pageviews and template files,
>   add the following to the functions.php.

```
// add category nicenames in body and post class
function category_id_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category)
        $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'category_id_class');
add_filter('body_class', 'category_id_class');
```